# DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found on Windows7 32-bit machine?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I am creating dll in windows7 professional 32 bit machine ,same dll registering another 32 bit windows7 professional service pack 1 machine this dll is not registered showing below error.

Unable to load DLL 'coredll.dll': The specified module could not be found.

[image]

How to resolve the compatabilty problem?
Regards
Narasimha

Comment: Coredll.dll is a component of Windows Mobile.  Clearly this code is never going to run on Windows7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a DLL requires that all dependencies of the DLL are resolved. You should use the Dependency Walker to get the list of DLLs that are required. When you copy the Dependency Walker to the target machine it should display the missing DLL immediately.

When you create a DLL from VC++ it requires usually the VCxxRT (Visual C++ run time) DLls. These DLLs come in different versions. When you target machine has not installed the correct version you get this error.

Check the installed version by looking at C:\Windows\winsxs for `x86_microsoft.vcXX.crt_*`.

**EDIT**: Hans' comment is correct. coredll.dll is a Windows CE DLL. It makes no sense to run regsvr32 with a DLL that requires coredll.dll at your PC. You can check this with:

```
dumpbin /headers IPTCExt.dll | find "subsystem"
```